# Android min api level

Tags: android, emulation, compatibility, android-min-sdk, target-sdk

I have 2 questions.
If I compiled my app with `targetSDKVersion 23` but tested it on an emulator running `api level 19`, will I be sure that it runs on a device with `api level 19`?

When I set `minSDKVersion` to an `API level` and use something that is not available on that api level will I get a compiler error?  If not how can I be sure on what is the `minimum api level` my program is compatible with?

Answer (score 1):

> If I compiled my app with targetSDKVersion 23 but tested it on an emulator running api level 19

The `targetSdkVersion` won't change your code or how it's run on a device.

> When I set minSDKVersion to an API level and use something that is not available on that api level will I get a compiler error?

You won't get a compiler error - you'll get a lint warning. If you actually run on a device without that API, you'll get a runtime error.

> how can I be sure on what is the minimum api level

At runtime you can query the SDK level of the device:

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` will be the API level.

You can then perform checks using the constants to degrade gracefully:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // fallback
} else {
    // use your lollipop api
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant compileSdkVersion in Android Studio, I used 23, but the device I want it to run has 19.  If it works in the emulator with api level 19 it means it will work on the device with the same api level, right?

Comment: "Will work" it could fail on device for any number of reasons: all devices are different, there are different implementations of Android with different bugs to each other. Yes I would expect it to work in the general case though.